# changing fields.selection choices dynamically

Tags: python, python-2.7, odoo, odoo-8

> **Objective**: Month field will show current month and previous month till 10th of
>   current month, for 11th it will only show option of current month.

I have looked for questions with similar problems and tried all the things i could, so Here's what i have tried so far-

.py

```
MONTH_LIST = [
    ('january','JANUARY'),
    ('february','FEBRUARY'),
    ('march','MARCH'),
    ('april','APRIL'),
    ('may','MAY'),
    ('june','JUNE'),
    ('july','JULY'),
    ('august','AUGUST'),
    ('september','SEPTEMBER'),
    ('october','OCTOBER'),
    ('november','NOVEMBER'),
    ('december','DECEMBER')
    ]


def _get_month(self, cr, uid, ids, field_name, arg, context=None):
        val = {}
        date_now = datetime.datetime.now()
        day = date_now.day
        month = date_now.month

        if day<10:
            val['month_val'] = MONTH_LIST[month-1][1] + MONTH_LIST[month-2][1]
        else:
            val['month_val'] = MONTH_LIST[month-1][1]

        return val


'month_val': fields.function(_get_month,  string='Month', type='selection', selection=MONTH_LIST, required=True),
```

Traceback-

```
2019-06-07 12:51:43,029 20396 INFO expensetest werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [07/Jun/2019 12:51:43] "GET /web/binary/image?model=hr.employee&field=image_medium&id=283 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
2019-06-07 12:51:43,109 20396 INFO expensetest werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [07/Jun/2019 12:51:43] "POST /web/dataset/call_kw/hr.expense.expense/fields_view_get HTTP/1.1" 200 -
2019-06-07 12:51:43,121 20396 INFO expensetest werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [07/Jun/2019 12:51:43] "GET /web/binary/image?model=hr.employee&field=image_medium&id=257 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
2019-06-07 12:51:43,128 20396 INFO expensetest werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [07/Jun/2019 12:51:43] "GET /web/binary/image?model=hr.employee&field=image_medium&id=265 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
2019-06-07 12:51:43,187 20396 INFO expensetest werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [07/Jun/2019 12:51:43] "GET /web/binary/image?model=hr.employee&field=image_medium&id=217 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
2019-06-07 12:51:43,404 20396 ERROR expensetest openerp.http: Exception during JSON request handling.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Odoo 8.0-20150515\server\.\openerp\http.py", line 530, in _handle_exception
  File "C:\Program Files\Odoo 8.0-20150515\server\.\openerp\http.py", line 567, in dispatch
  File "C:\Program Files\Odoo 8.0-20150515\server\.\openerp\http.py", line 303, in _call_function
  File "C:\Program Files\Odoo 8.0-20150515\server\.\openerp\service\model.py", line 113, in wrapper
  File "C:\Program Files\Odoo 8.0-20150515\server\.\openerp\http.py", line 300, in checked_call
  File "C:\Program Files\Odoo 8.0-20150515\server\.\openerp\http.py", line 796, in __call__
  File "C:\Program Files\Odoo 8.0-20150515\server\.\openerp\http.py", line 396, in response_wrap
  File "C:\Program Files\Odoo 8.0-20150515\server\openerp\addons\web\controllers\main.py", line 876, in search_read
  File "C:\Program Files\Odoo 8.0-20150515\server\openerp\addons\web\controllers\main.py", line 897, in do_search_read
  File "C:\Program Files\Odoo 8.0-20150515\server\.\openerp\http.py", line 901, in proxy
  File "C:\Program Files\Odoo 8.0-20150515\server\.\openerp\api.py", line 241, in wrapper
  File "C:\Program Files\Odoo 8.0-20150515\server\.\openerp\models.py", line 5144, in search_read
  File "C:\Program Files\Odoo 8.0-20150515\server\.\openerp\api.py", line 241, in wrapper
  File "C:\Program Files\Odoo 8.0-20150515\server\.\openerp\models.py", line 3139, in read
  File "C:\Program Files\Odoo 8.0-20150515\server\.\openerp\api.py", line 239, in wrapper
  File "C:\Program Files\Odoo 8.0-20150515\server\.\openerp\models.py", line 3174, in read
  File "C:\Program Files\Odoo 8.0-20150515\server\.\openerp\api.py", line 239, in wrapper
  File "C:\Program Files\Odoo 8.0-20150515\server\.\openerp\models.py", line 3355, in _read_from_database
KeyError: 1479
```

Thanks in advance for the support.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you cannot do this In Odoo, The values of the selection are created when Odoo start and they cannot be modified.
Once the selection is filled up with chooses it cannot be altered.
Try to use `many2one` you can change the domain dynamically, and even with `many2one` if you use `widget="selection"` you will have a problem when the *domain is changed* you have to access the field two times to see that the list is changed.

Comment: Well, i got my desired output with selection field i.e instead of fields.function i used fields.selection.

Comment: Don't know what you mean, From what I understood that you want to change the value of option of selection dynamically? I didn't know that you just want to create Selection field

Comment: I meant selection field dynamically,i.e. now the month_val field is `'month_val': fields.selection(_get_month, string='Month'),`